# Camera / Perception Tutorials in ROS

Tags: ros, tutorial, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm working with 2 robots, each one with one camera. I'm first simulating the robots. Are there any tutorials about Vision in ROS?

Where you can learn the basics? I had courses in Image processing and Vision but I never worked with image/cameras with ROS.

I'm doing the Visualisation tutorial but I think this is not what I want....Any recommendations?

Thx you so much!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/204415/camera-/-perception-tutorials-in-ros/) by [End-Effector](https://answers.ros.org/users/7606/end-effector/) on ROS Answers with karma: 162 on 2015-03-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Although not free, I would strongly recommend @Pi Robot's book [ROS by Example](http://www.lulu.com/shop/r-patrick-goebel/ros-by-example-indigo-volume-1/ebook/product-22015937.html) for vision-perception educational contents using ROS. This book is collective, exhaustive, and insightful.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2015-03-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [End-Effector](https://answers.ros.org/users/7606/end-effector/) on 2015-03-10**:
Thx you so much friend.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I guess most people use OpenCV. You can just use image_transport to subscribe. The [basic tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/image_transport/Tutorials) should get you there. From then on it's just whatever opencv has to offer.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2015-03-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [End-Effector](https://answers.ros.org/users/7606/end-effector/) on 2015-03-10**:
I installed OpenCV last friday, my teacher Vsion & Image Processing teacher said that if we used it we would have zero. So Never work with it.

The answer I wanted was this one: http://wiki.ros.org/Sensors/Cameras

It should be in THE BEGINNER TUTORIALS PAGE but its not, its hidden.

Thx you friend.